# Retornar el valor de una promesa y alamacenarla en una variable en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola necesito retornar el valor a la variable final pero no me ha sido posible me podrian ayudar o decir que estoy haciedno mal siempre devuleve "Promise "

```
const flag = fetch("/store/api/features")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((flag) => {

            const CorpAuthFlag = flag.features.find((element) => element === 'domain-auth');
            if(CorpAuthFlag === 'domain-auth') {
            return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

    });

async function switchFlag() {
    let a = await flag;
    return a;
}

let showDomainAuth = switchFlag();
```

Comment: @Samuel, actualice la respuesta, encontrarás ejemplos en React para tu caso de uso, la primera respuesta fue con el espíritu de decirte como manejar operaciones asincrónicas, saludos

Answer (score 3):

No hay ningún error, solo hay que revisar los conceptos de asincronia y saber como manejar las respuestas asincrónicas.

El propósito de una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) es manejar operaciones asincrónicas usando funciones de continuación , el método `fetch` regresa una promesa.

Observa el [diagrama](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) que viene en el enlace, ahí veras que ya tienes la promesa con estatus **pendiente**, ahora debes trabajar con su resultado usando funciones de continuación `then`.

Lo que intentas hacer es un patrón inválido, cuando se tiene una `Promesa`:

- Se puede trabajar la respuesta dentro de la función de continuación `then`.
- Se puede trabajar la respuesta dentro de la función `asycn/await`.

Ahora, si se trabaja con la `Promesa`, se debe estructurar el código de forma asincrónica con funciones de continuación `then`.

Por otro lado, con `async/await` se puede estructurar el código de forma más sincrónica, siempre y cuando se haga dentro de la funcion `async`.

Aquí, repito tu código con comentarios para que lo revises nuevamente:

```
const flag = fetch("/store/api/features")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((flag) => {
          
          if(flag.data.length !== 0 ) {
          return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }

  });

  async function switchFlag() {
    let a = await flag;
    console.log("Asycn/await En este scope estructuro código de forma sincrónica");
    //aqui ya se ve true / false
    console.log("a= ", a);
    //aqui un setState x ejemplo
    //o regreso la promesa
    return a;
  }

  let showDomainAuth = switchFlag();
  //tengo la promesa
  console.log("showDomainAuth",showDomainAuth);
  //Promise:estructuro el código de forma asincronica con funciones de continuacion
  showDomainAuth.then(res=>{
    //aqui ya se ve true / false
    console.log("continuation then", res);
    //aqui un setState x ejemplo
  })
```

Muy importante, las operaciones asincrónicas (llamadas API en este caso) en react, se ejecutan usualmente en métodos como `componentDidMount` o `useEffect`, esto para evitar **re-renders** innecesarios.

#### Ejemplos React basados en tu código original.

Método `componentDidMount` Class Component, solo se llama a la API cuando el componente ya ha sido cargado, se observa como se usa `const flag` de forma sincrónica dentro de la función `async/await` switchFlag`:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        showDomainAuth:false
      }
      this.switchFlag = this.switchFlag.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.switchFlag();
  }

  switchFlag = async () => {
    
      const flag = await fetch("/store/api/features")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((flag) => {
         
          const CorpAuthFlag = flag.features.find((element) => element === 'domain-auth');
          if(CorpAuthFlag === 'domain-auth') {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
      })
     
      console.log("response await",flag);
      this.setState({showDomainAuth:flag})
      
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                {this.state.showDomainAuth ? `it's domain-auth` : `it isn't domain-auth`}
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Ejemplo con React `useEffect` Hook Functional Component, se especifica que el hook `useEffect` solo va a ejecutarse una vez (skip effects) declarando su array de dependencias vacío; esto es cuando el componente ya se haya cargado, de lo contrario se estará ejecutando en cada render y se tendrán problemas de llamadas API en loop:

```
function App() {
  const [showDomainAuth, setShowDomainAuth] = useState(false)

  const switchFlag = async () => {
    
    const flag = await fetch("/store/api/features")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((flag) => {
        const CorpAuthFlag = flag.features.find((element) => element === 'domain-auth');
        if(CorpAuthFlag === 'domain-auth') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    })
   
    console.log("response await hook",flag);
    setShowDomainAuth(flag)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      switchFlag();
  }, [])
  
  return (
      <div>
          <h1>
              {showDomainAuth ? `it's domain-auth` : `it isn't domain-auth`}
          </h1>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Ambas soluciones estan basadas en tu código original, conforme vayas adquiriendo experiencia con el manejo de operaciones asincrónicas, encontrarás mejores patrones.

Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Si no se hace dentro de un useEffect o un componentDidMount el número de llamados a la api será igual al número de renders que haga el componente. No es optimo hacerlo fuera de estas funciones

Comment: @SantiagoRuiz, claro, la respuesta tiene ahora los ejemplos en el contexto React, saludos

Answer (score 0):

**React**

```javascript
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function App() {
    const [showDomainAuth, setShowDomainAuth] = useState(false)

    const switchFlag = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("/store/api/features");
        if(response) {
            const flag = response.json();
            setShowDomainAuth(flag.features.some((element) => element === 'domain-auth'));
        }
    
        return setShowDomainAuth(false)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        switchFlag();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                {showDomainAuth ? `it's domain-auth` : `it isn't domain-auth`}
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'))
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Hay que darle una segunda revisión a esta respuesta, hay problemas con la lógica.