# Porque me retorna Pending la función?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, async-await, async

La siguiente función hace un llamado a una api con axios y estoy usando async, await pero devuelve `Pending { <pending> }` cuando hago `return bookSort;` de todas maneras. Pero cuando dejo sin return a la función y solo hago un `console.log(booksSort)` si muestra en consola el array

```
import api from '../../utils/axios/axios.js';

async function anyComments(arr) {
  const booksCommented = arr.filter(book => book.comment.length > 0);

  const idsArray = booksCommented.map(b => b.id);

  let booksWithComments = [];
  let newBooksList = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < idsArray.length; i++) {
    const info = await api.get(`/book/${idsArray[i]}`);

    // newBooksList.push(info.data.comment);
    let sum = 0;

    for (let y = 0; y < info.data.comment.length; y++) {
      if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(info.data.comment[y].rate))) {
        sum += parseInt(info.data.comment[y].rate);
      }
    }

    let averageRating = Math.round(sum / info.data.comment.length);
    let newObj = { ...info.data, rating: averageRating };
    booksWithComments.push(newObj);
  }

  let booksSort = booksWithComments.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.rating - a.rating;
  });

  return booksSort;
}

console.log(anyComments(arrayDeObjetos));
```

Comment: Puedes revisar las [siguientes publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/426878/101408) para mas información

Answer (score 1):

Esa es la gracia de que una función sea asíncrona. El código puede tardar más o menos en terminar de ejecutarse. La forma en que Javascript representa estas operaciones es mediante `Promise`.

Entonces, según [este sitio](https://www.tabnine.com/academy/javascript/how-to-use-promises-in-javascript/) puedes acceder al resultado de dos formas.

- Mediante la función `then` del `Promise`.

  Esta función recibe 2 parámetros, son 2 funciones que se ejecutarán cuando el `Promise` se resuelva (la función original termine). La primera en caso de que termine bien y la segunda en caso de que termine mal.

  Por ejemplo, si quieres imprimir el resultado, puedes escribir el siguiente código:

  ```
  anyComments(...).then(resultado => console.log(resultado), error => console.log(error))
  ```
- Usando `async/await`.

  Cómo quizá ya sepas, `await` espera el resultado de una función asíncrona o un `Promise`.

  Esta es una forma más limpia de escribir el código.

  Aunque el requisito para poder usar `await` debe estar en una función o lambda `async`.

  Un código funcionalmente equivalente al anterior sería:

  ```
  async function getAndPrintBooksWithComments(){
      try {
          let resultado = await anyComments(...) 
          console.log(resultado)
      }
      catch (error){
           console.log(error)
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: En realidad yo solo quiero que devuelva el resultado con un return

Comment: @José entonces no podrás usar Promises ni funciones asíncronas.

Comment: porque? y que uso?

Comment: @José no lo sé. No creo que haya un sustituto. Depende del uso que le quieras dar al resultado deberías ver cómo adaptar el código.

Comment: Voy a usarlo sin envolverlo a una función solo pondré la lógica dentro del componente